# LocalProccessingException was unhandled rdlc PDF c# export

Tags: c#, exception, report, rdlc

I am attempting to write a function to save a rdlc report as a pdf to a specified location, but I am getting the exception

> "The report definition for report 'Reports/AsrPhoneList.rdlc' has not
>   been specified".

If theres anything redundant let me know, I am new to this.

```
void SaveReport()
{
     Warning[] warnings;
     string[] streamids;
     string mimeType;
     string encoding;
     string filenameExtension;
     string saveFilePath = string.Concat(@"c:\Users\", windowsUserName, @"\Desktop\CurrentStatus.pdf");
     ReportViewer reportViewer = new ReportViewer();
     reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Reports/AsrPhoneList.rdlc";
     reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
     byte[] bytes = reportViewer.LocalReport.Render(
            "PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension,
            out streamids, out warnings);

     using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(saveFilePath, FileMode.Create))
     {
         fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
     }
}
```

Comment: Do you set the property "Build Action" of the *rdlc* to "Content"?

Comment: Build Action: Embedded Resource. Copy to Output Directory: Tried all 3 options (Copy if Newer, Copy Always, Do Not Copy) with both BuildAction=Embedded Resource andContent and none of the combinations work.

Comment: Does it work...?

Comment: No it does not work @BekaChkopoia

Comment: Try to replace report path with: "Reports.AsrPhoneList.rdlc"

Comment: Still doesn't work @InitK